# Efficient decoding of binary and text structures (packets)

Tags: java, decode, network-protocols

**Background**

There is a well-known tool called [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). I've been using it for ages. It is great, but performance is the problem. Common usage scenario includes several data preparation steps in order to extract a data subset to be analyzed later. Without that step it takes minutes to do filtering (with big traces Wireshark is next to unusable).

[image]

The actual idea is to create a better solution, fast, parallel and efficient, to be used as a data aggregator/storage.

**Requirements**

The actual requirement is to use all power provided by modern hardware. I should say there is a room for different types of optimization and I hope I did a good job on upper layers, but technology is the main question right now. According to the current design there are several flavors of packet decoders (dissectors):

- *interactive decoders*: decoding logic can be easily changed in runtime. Such approach can be quite useful for protocol developers -- decoding speed is not that critical, but flexibility and fast results are more important
- *embeddable decoders*: can be used as a library.This type is supposed to have good performance and be flexible enough to use all available CPUs and cores
- *decoders as a service*: can be accessed through a clean API. This type should provide best of the breed performance and efficiency

**Results**

My current solution is JVM-based decoders. The actual idea is to reuse the code, eliminate porting, etc, but still have good efficiency.

- *Interactive decoders*: implemented on Groovy
- *Embeddable decoders*: implemented on Java
- *Decoders as a service*: Tomcat + optimizations + embeddable decoders wrapped into a servlet (binary in, XML out)

**Problems to be solved**

- Groovy provides way to much power and everything, but lucks expressiveness in this particular case
- Decoding protocol into a tree structure is a dead end -- too many resources are simply wasted
- Memory consumption is somewhat hard to control. I did several optimizations but still not happy with profiling results
- Tomcat with various bells and whistles still introduces to much overhead (mainly connection handling)

Am I doing right using JVM everywhere? Do you see any other good and elegant way to achieve the initial goal: get easy-to-write highly scalable and efficient protocol decoders?

The protocol, format of the results, etc are not fixed.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? This is incredibly open-ended. I don't really know what kind of answers you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with @JohnKugelman, this could be a great question, but as stated it's too broad. I would try to remove as much as possible and try to keep the information relevant to what you're really asking (about decoding protocol frames). You spend 4 paragaphs and 2 bulleted lists talking about extra stuff and only 1 sentence with your real question.

Comment: I've edited the question providing valuable details and removing some other stuff. There is no one and only solution. Several or maybe a lot of valuable answers might be proposed, providing interesting insights, describing unusual techniques and highlighting good architectural solutions.

Comment: Is the format of the buffers already fixed?  (seems like it is from the picture).  If _not_, have you looked at Google's ProtocolBuffers or Hadoop's serialization code, which is highly optimized for speed over the network?

Comment: The buffers are not fixed. I have ProtoBuf, Thrift, Avro and several other options in my list, but currently I really want to get rid of any hierarchical structure. Actually I managed to do that. Tree form seems to be needed only as a part of presentation layer, which means I can introduce another type of decoder (GUI oriented) or just have a tree structure template filled with a data decoded into a flat structure.

Comment: I suggest you start by getting rid of all the scope creep. If the objective is better performance than Wireshark, introducing interactivity, SaaS, Tomcat, XML, etc., into this is completely counterproductive.

Comment: It will be quite a hard task to find a niche for a product without that scope. I do not want to end up with good but useless performance. Tomcat, XML and finally JVM can be thrown away. I believe there are a lot of better solutions, but it would be great to keep simplified authoring, good performance and some sort of SaaS. BTW, it is not that hard to be better than Wireshark in terms of performance. The idea is to have way better performance to deal with modern data flows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found several possible improvements:

**Interactive decoders**

Groovy expressiveness can be greatly improved, by extending Groovy syntax using 
[AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations). So it would be possible to simplify decoders authoring still providing good performance. AST (stands for Abstract Syntax Tree) is a compile-time technique.

> When the Groovy compiler compiles Groovy scripts and classes, at some
>   point in the process, the source code will end up being represented in
>   memory in the form of a Concrete Syntax Tree, then transformed into an
>   Abstract Syntax Tree. The purpose of AST Transformations is to let
>   developers hook into the compilation process to be able to modify the
>   AST before it is turned into bytecode that will be run by the JVM.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel introducing yet another language to define/describe a protocol structure (it is enough to have [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)). The idea is to simplify decoders development in order to provide some fast prototyping technique. Basically, some kind of DSL is to be introduced.

[Further reading](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=groovy%20DSL&ie=UTF-8)

**Embeddable decoders**

Java can introduce some additional overhead. There are several libraries to address that issue:

- [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html)
- [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)
- [Javolution](http://javolution.org/)
- [Commons-primitives](http://commons.apache.org/primitives/)

[image]

Frankly speaking I do not see any other option except Java for this layer.

**Decoders as a service**

No Java is needed on this layer. Finally I have a good option to go but price is quite high. [GWan](http://gwan.ch/) looks really good.

[image]

Some additional porting will be required, but it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 3):

This problem seems to share the same characteristic of many high-performance I/O implementation problems, which is that the number of memory copies dominates performance. The scatter-gather interface patterns for asynchronous I/O follow from this principle. With scatter-gather, blocks of memory are operated on in place. As long as the protocol decoders take block streams as input rather than byte streams, you'll have eliminated a lot of the performance overhead of moving memory around to preserve the byte stream abstraction. The byte stream is a very good abstraction for saving engineering time, but not so good for high-performance I/O.

In a related issue, I'd beware of the JVM just because of the basic type `String`. I can't say I'm familiar with how `String` is implemented in the JVM, but I do imagine that there's not a way of making a string out of a block list without doing a memory copy. On the other hand, a native kind of string that could, and which interoperated with the JVM `String` compatibly could be a way of splitting the difference.

---

The other aspect of this problem that seems relevant is that of formal languages. In the spirit of not copying blocks of memory, you also don't want to be scanning the same block of memory over and over. Since you want to make run-time changes, that means you probably don't want to use a precompiled state machine, but rather a recursive descent parser that can dispatch to an appropriate protocol interpreter at each level of descent. There are some complications involved when an outer layer does not specify the type of an inner layer. Those complications are worse when you don't even get the length of the inner content, since then you're relying on the inner content to be well formed to prevent runaway. Nevertheless, it's worth putting some attention into understand how many times a single block will be scanned.

Comment: Strings are often, but not always, interned in a long-lived pool. Strings can be pre-combined with StringBuilder (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

Network traffic is growing ([some analytics](http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/03/mobile-data-use-to-grow-300-globally-by-2017-led-by-video-web-traffic-says-strategy-analytics/)), so there will be a need to process more and more data per second.

The only way to achieve that is to use more CPU power, but CPU frequency is stable. Only number of cores is growing. It looks like the only way is to use available cores more efficiently and scale better.

[image]