# Dynamic recognition and handling of protocol data units in bytestream

Tags: java, oop, parsing, design-patterns, protocols

I implemented a protocol for a little multiplayer game. It was based on bytes, so to *deserialize* the received messages I had to iterate over the byte stream and parse it bit by bit. After I had all the bytes and knew the message type, I threw the bytes in a reverse constructor that constructed the protocol data unit from the raw bytes.

This whole process was very ugly, not really OO and had unreadable *if/else* code.
I had to implement the `reverseConstructor(byte[] bytes)` for every protocol data unit (pdu) I added. An approach where some kind of schema is defined per pdu (e. g. schema = [1 byte int (id = x), x bytes ascii string, 4 bytes double]), and where the handling of the bytes is done with that schema, would be more elegant.

<s>I got a hint here on SO to use google's protobufs</s> *(Apparently they are not fitting my needs, since I would have to change the protocol to adhere to protobuf standards).*

**INFO**

I can't change the protocol. There are **two** different scenarios (I **don't** want to support them at the same time or even in the same program):

- The protocol data units have a length field encoded in the header
- The protocol data units have no length field, but one can derive from the message type when/where the message ends.

I personally am a fan of length fields. But sometimes you have to adhere to a protocol that somebody else designed. So the protocols are fix. They all have a header which contains the protocol id, the *unique message id*, and in the first scenario a length field.

**QUESTION**

Can anyone give me a very small example with two simple protocol data units that are parsed by a efficient, generic receive method? The only examples I found in the protobuf tutorials were of type: user a sends message x, user b expects message X and can deserialize it without problem.

But what if user b has to be prepared for message x, y and z. How can one handle this situation without much code duplication in an intelligent way.

I would also appreciate hints to design principles that enable me to achieve greater code here without the use of a extern library.

---

**EDIT**

I think sth like that is the way to go. You can find more of the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/aio-lan-server/source/browse/trunk/src/main/lion/netio/codec/ProtobufDecoder.java).
The bytes are read dynamically till an object is found, and then the position of the buffer is reset.

```
                while (true) {
                        if (buffer.remaining() < frameLength) {
                                buffer.reset();
                                break;
                        }
                        if (frameLength > 0) {
                                Object resultObj = prototype.newBuilderForType().mergeFrom(buffer.array(), buffer.arrayOffset() + buffer.position(), frameLength).build();
                                client.fireMessageReceived(resultObj);
                                buffer.position(buffer.position() + frameLength);
                                buffer.mark();
                        }
                        if (buffer.remaining() > fieldSize) {
                                frameLength = getFrameLength(buffer);
                        } else {
                                break;
                        }
                }
```

JavaDoc - **mergeFrom**

> Parse data as a message of this type and merge it with the message being built. This is just a small wrapper around MessageLite.Builder.mergeFrom(CodedInputStream).
>   <sup>[https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message.Builder#mergeFrom(byte[])](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message.Builder#mergeFrom%28byte%5B%5D%29)</sup>

The problem is the part *message of this type*, but it should be possible to address this issue with a generic approach.

---

**SAMPLE**

Here is a sample protocol data unit. It has a length field. There is another scenario where the pdus have no length field. This pdu is of variable size. There are also pdus of fixed size.

[image: sample pdu]

For completeness' sake. Here the representation of strings in the protocol data units.

[image: strings in pdu]

Comment: I created a byte protocol parser that can be configured via xml. Maybe you're interested https://github.com/mbe24/protege

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Protocol design**

Frankly, it is a common mistake to create a first protocol implementation without any further  changes in mind. Just as an exercise, let's try to design flexible protocol.

[image]

Basically, the idea is to have several frames encapsulated into each other. Please note, you have **Payload ID** available, so it is easy to identify next frame in the sequence.

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) in order to see real-life protocols usually follow the same principle.

[image]

Such approach simplifies packet dissection a lot, but it is still possible to deal with other protocols.

**2. Protocol decoding(dissection)**

I spent quite a lot of time developing next generation network analyzer for my previous company.

[image]

Can't expose all the details, but one of the key features was flexible protocol stack, capable of identifying protocol frames. [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) is a good example, because there is no hint on the lower layer (usually UDP) next frame is a RTP frame. Special VM was developed to execute dissectors and control the process.

The good news I have smaller personal projects with Java-based dissectors (I'll skip some javadocs in order to save several lines).

```
/**
 * High-level dissector contract definition. Dissector is meant to be a simple
 * protocol decoder, which analyzes protocol binary image and produces number
 * of fields.
 *
 * @author Renat.Gilmanov
 */
public interface Dissector {

    /**
     * Returns dissector type.
     */
    DissectorType getType();

    /**
     * Verifies packet data belongs to the protocol represented by this dissector.
     */
    boolean isProtocol(DataInput input, Dissection dissection);

    /**
     * Performs the dissection.
     */
    Dissection dissect(DataInput input, Dissection dissection);

    /**
     * Returns a protocol which corresponds to the current dissector.
     *
     * @return a protocol instance
     */
    Protocol getProtocol();
}
```

Protocol itself knows upper layer protocol, so when there is no direct hint available it is possible to iterate through known protocols and use *isProtocol* method in order to identify the next frame.

```
public interface Protocol {

    // ...

    List<Protocol> getUpperProtocols(); }
```

As I said RTP protocol is a bit tricky to handle:

[image]

So let's check implementation details. Verification is based on several known facts about the protocol:

```
/**
 * Verifies current frame belongs to RTP protocol.
 *
 * @param input data input
 * @param dissection initial dissection
 * @return true if protocol frame is RTP
 */
@Override
public final boolean isProtocol(final DataInput input, final Dissection dissection) {
    int available = input.available();
    byte octet    = input.getByte();
    byte version  = getVersion(octet);
    byte octet2   = input.getByte(1);
    byte pt       = (byte) (octet2 & 0x7F);

    return ((pt < 0x47) & (RTP_VERSION == version));
}
```

Dissection is just a set of basic operations:

public final Dissection dissect(DataInput input, Dissection d) {

```
    // --- protocol header --------------------------------
    final byte octet1 = input.getByte(0);
    final byte version = getVersion(octet1);
    final byte p = (byte) ((octet1 & 0x20) >> 5);
    final byte x = (byte) ((octet1 & 0x10) >> 4);
    final byte cc = (byte) ((octet1 & 0x0F));

    //...

    // --- seq --------------------------------------------
    final int seq = (input.getInt() & 0x0000FFFF);
    final int timestamp = input.getInt();
    final int ssrc = input.getInt();
```

Finally you can define a Protocol stack:

```
public interface ProtocolStack {

    String getName();

    Protocol getRootProtocol();

    Dissection dissect(DataInput input, Dissection dissection, DissectOptions options);
}
```

Under the hood it handles all the complexity and decodes a packet, frame by frame. The biggest challenge is to make the dissection process bullet-proof and stable. Using such or similar approach you'll be able to organize you protocol decoding code. It is likely proper implementation of **isProtocol** will let you handle different version and so on. Anyway, I would not say this approach is simple, but it provides a lot of flexibility and control.

**3. Is there any universal solution?**

Yes, there is [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One):

> Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1) is a standard and notation that
>   describes rules and structures for representing, encoding,
>   transmitting, and decoding data in telecommunications and computer
>   networking. The formal rules enable representation of objects that are
>   independent of machine-specific encoding techniques. Formal notation
>   makes it possible to automate the task of validating whether a
>   specific instance of data representation abides by the specifications.
>   In other words, software tools can be used for the validation.

Here is an example of a protocol defined using ASN.1:

```
FooProtocol DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

    FooQuestion ::= SEQUENCE {
        trackingNumber INTEGER,
        question       IA5String
    }

    FooAnswer ::= SEQUENCE {
        questionNumber INTEGER,
        answer         BOOLEAN
    }

END
```

BTW, there is [Java Asn.1 Compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/) available:

> JAC (Java Asn1 Compiler) is a tool for you if you want to (1)parse
>   your asn1 file (2)create .java classes and (3)encode/decode instances
>   of your classes. Just forget all asn1 byte streams, and take the
>   advantage of OOP! BER, CER and DER are all supported.

**Finally**

I usually recommend to do several simple PoCs in order to find best possible solution. I decided not to use ASN.1 in order to reduce complexity and have some room for optimization, but it might help you.

Anyway, try everything you can and let us know about the results :)

You can also check the following topic: [Efficient decoding of binary and text structures (packets)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649233/1435741)

**4. Update: bidirectional approach**

I'm sorry for quite a long answer. I just want you to have enough options to find best possible solution. Answering the question regarding bidirectional approach:

- **Option 1**: you can use symmetrical serialization approach: define DataOutput, write serialization logic -- you are done. I will just recommend to looks through BerkeleyDB API and [TupleBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/bind/tuple/TupleBinding.html). It does solve the same problem providing a full control on store/restore procedure.

> This class takes care of converting the entries to/from TupleInput and
>   TupleOutput objects. Its two abstract methods must be implemented by a
>   concrete subclass to convert between tuples and key or data objects.

```
entryToObject(TupleInput)
objectToEntry(Object,TupleOutput)
```

- **Option 2**: The most universal way is to define your structure containing a set of fields. Every field requires the following information:

  - name
  - type
  - size (bits)

For example, for RTP it will look like the following:

```
Version:          byte (2 bits)
Padding:          bool (1 bit)
Extension:        bool (1 bit)
CSRC Count:       byte (4 bits) 
Marker:           bool (1 bit)
Payload Type:     byte (7 bits)
Sequence Number:  int  (16 bits)
```

Having that you can define generic way of reading/writing such structures. Closest working example I know is [Javolution Struct](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html). Please look through, they have a really good examples:

```
class Clock extends Struct { // Hardware clock mapped to memory.
     Unsigned16 seconds  = new Unsigned16(5); // unsigned short seconds:5 bits
     Unsigned16 minutes  = new Unsigned16(5); // unsigned short minutes:5 bits
     Unsigned16 hours    = new Unsigned16(4); // unsigned short hours:4 bits
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Incisive answer. Quite a lot to digest. So the approach is to check if `isProtocol()` is true and to put the return value of `getProtocol()` on the stack, I guess. And in `Dissection` you have all the byte operations e.g. `createUtfFromByte()`, `getVersion()` to keep them separated from the rest of the code? I think I can utilize your approach. But I don't have frames, I'm handling just one type of protocol. Also you provided 'just' the decoding/dissection direction, I still have not much clue how to define a bidirectional approach that shares code for encoding/decoding of the messages.

Comment: Yes, the PoC is a very good idea. The protocol handling could be hided behind some kind of communicator inferface that uses the strategy pattern to change the decoding/encoding mechanics.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I also wanted to accepted Groo's one, since his answer was more related. But you provided a broader range of approaches I could utilize. Thx!

Comment: I got some more understanding on the topic and created a generic parser, that can be configured via xml. Each protocol unit consists of 'elements', which are iterated over, while reading/writing the bytes https://github.com/mbe24/protege

Answer (score 2):

(Note: it's been a while since I've used Java so I wrote this in C#, but you should get the general idea)

The general idea is:

1. Each of your parsers should be basically represented as an interface, or a delegate (or a method, or a function pointer) with a signature of something like:

   ```
   interface IParser<T>
   {   
        IParserResult<T> Parse(IIndexable<byte> input);
   }
   ```
2. The result of the parsing operation is an instance of the `IParserResult<T>` interface, which should tell you the following:

   - Whether the parsing succeeded,
   - If it failed, why it failed (not enough data to finish parsing, not the right parser, or CRC error, or exception while parsing),
   - If it succeeded, the actual parsed message value,
   - If it succeeded, the next parser offset.

   In other words, something like:

   ```
   interface IParserResult<T>
   {
        boot Success { get; } 
        ErrorType Error { get; } // in case it failed
        T Result { get; } // null if failed
        int BytesToSkip { get; } // if success, number of bytes to advance 
   }
   ```
3. Your parser thread should iterate through a list of parsers and check results. It should look more or less like this:

   ```
   // presuming inputFifo is a Queue<byte> 
   while (inputFifo.ContainsData) 
   {
        foreach (IParser parser in ListOfParsers) 
        {
            var result = parser.Parse(inputFifo);

            if (result.Success) 
            {
                FireMessageReceived(result.Value);
                inputFifo.Skip(result.BytesToSkip);
                break;
            }

            // wrong parser? try the next one
            if (result.ErrorType == ErrorType.UnsupportedData)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // otherwise handle errors
            switch (result.ErrorType) 
            {
                ...
            }
        }
   }
   ```

The `IIndexable<byte>` interface is not a part of .NET, but it's rather important for avoiding numerous array allocations (this is the [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233738/IIndexable-a-true-read-only-list-interface)).

The good thing about this approach is that the `Parse` method can do a whole lot of checks to determine if it "supports" a certain message (check the cookie, length, crc, whatever). We use this approach when parsing data which is constantly being received on a separate thread from unreliable connections, so each parser also returns a "NotEnoughData" error if the length is too short to tell if the message is valid or not (in which case the loop breaks and waits for more data).

**[Edit]**

Additionally (if this also helps you), we use a list (or a dictionary to be precise) of "message consumers" which are strongly typed and tied to a certain parser/message type. This way only the interested parties are notified when a certain message is parsed. It's basically a simple messaging system where you need to create a list of parsers, and a dictionary of mappings (message type -> message consumer).

Comment: Nice approach, but I don't think it works without the indexable list wrapper you mentioned, since in case of a wrong parser the next one has to start at the *last successfully parsed index*. And for many protocol data units it might be a little overhead. Also whilst adding a new protocol data unit I would always have to deal with raw bytes. I had the idea of implementing some kind of schema or byte regex. But thx for your approach, it was great input. Waaay cleaner than the code I created.

Comment: @mike: the point of the wrapper is to allow iterating over the actual array by simply offsetting the index. If you use a plain `byte[]` array, then you need to copy it every time you make an offset (at least in .NET). Since we use a thin wrapper, we can abstract any input we want without creating a hard in-memory array (e.g. when parsing large disk streams we can wrap the actual stream and index it directly). But the example I posted uses a FIFO input buffer, which should skip data efficiently anyway (e.g. a circular array).

Comment: @mike: yes, we also thought of using some formal descriptive language to define our parsers, but in the end this proved to allow much greater flexibility, allowing more complex parsing scenarios. Oh, and yes, I thought your comment was that it would work better without the indexable wrapper, now I got it.

Comment: Okay, we're on the same page :) As I said I like you're approach, but I'm kind of struggling with the idea of deriving the right result by trial and error. But I'm goining to accept your answer, if I don't get more input on the 'byte regex' stuff, or other approaches the next days.

Comment: How would or how did you derive the bytes from the messages? Did the messages have a `toBytes()` method. Or did a extern module/class handle this?

Comment: @mike Actually we only created serialized representations of messages for unit testing as the code was meant only to parse protocols from various devices and respond with different messages. You might want to keep parsing (deserialization) and serialization logic separate from actual data classes to allow usimg different protocols and simplify versioning. If you need to support both directions, then it's reasonable to have both methods in the same class (although `Parser` would then not be the best naming choice).

Comment: For example, when implementing `ISerializable`, you always implement both read and write methods, so in this case I would just make the read method return more metadata to allow you to choose the appropriate parser. It may also seem like too much responsibility for a single method, but I am still not completely sure how you intend to use this. (typing on a phone, sorry for typos)

Comment: Thx for the input! What exactly is not clear about my intentions with this approach? If you need more detail to help me, I can provide it.

Comment: It makes sense to put the support for both directions in the same class. But the idea that I have to fully implement both directions, seems to hold some overhead. But maybe I'm thinking to functional here.

Comment: Yes, that way you basically need to do things twice. That's what I meant with "unsure how you intend to use it": if you're going to support lots of messages and protocols (e.g. like Wireshark does), then it makes sense to create a list of descriptors for each message and use them as rules for both directions. We did this once since we also didn't have an appropriate framework in .NET, but it had a simplified set of rules/data types (but it also gave us lots of useful metadata during parsing for each token in the message). Yeah, if there was such a fw for Java it would be neat.

Answer (score 1):

At the 10,000 ft. level, this a classic case where the Factory Pattern is useful. Your code will be much cleaner (and therefore easier to optimize) if you think of this problem in terms of the Factory Pattern (and I have written it the other way, so unfortunately I know -- what was several days of work reduced to a few hours once I applied the Factory Pattern).

*[edit...]*

For the bytes -> object case, you will need to read enough bytes to determine unambiguously which type of object has been passed down the wire, then proceed with parsing that object serialization.

Comment: I can only see one direction; how one can produce different messages with the factory pattern, and even within the messages a abstract `getBytes()` method that derives the byte representation (although I think transformation to bytes and back should be decoupled from the message object), but how would you apply the factory pattern to solve the problem 'bytes -> concrete message'. The methods @Groo provided are more or less the application of the factory pattern, where `IParser<T>` is the creator and the product is `IParserResult<T>` resp. the message of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a message (say myMessage) with optional messages for x, y, z. This is discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques). i.e. here is an example with Foo, Barr, Baz from the techniques document

```
message OneMessage {
    // One of the following will be filled in.
    optional Foo foo = 1;
    optional Bar bar = 2;
    optional Baz baz = 3;
}
```

Comment: What the link basically is saying is adujust your protocol to fit the the protobuf paradigm. I will update my question to make clear that the protocol is already developed and fix!

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Buffers define their own wire protocol based on binary tag/value pairs.  If you have a pre-existing protocol that you cannot change, you cannot use Protocol Buffers to parse it.

Comment: Would've been more of a comment, but thx. I guess I'm one option down now.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: the use of annotations like [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) does to automate the process of converting the message objects to their defined byte representation. It should also be able to recreate/unmarshal the raw bytes to message objects (but only in the scenario with the length field I guess).

But using annotations would include the use of some light reflection. Which could eventually decrease the performance(?).

Here's an example (...as I wrote the example, I came to the conclusion I could probably use the jaxb annotations. Since they also hanve `@XmlTypeAdapter` to also support maps etc.. Anyway, here the example):

```
/**
 * Annotation that helps identifying data elements for encoding/decoding
 * byte packets.
 * 
 * Annotate public getter methods in message classes.
 * 
 * NOTE: just primitive types and strings supported.
 *
 */
@Retention (value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target (value = ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MessageAttribute
{
  /* relative position of attribute in byte packet
   * 0 = first, 1 = second, etc.
   */
  int position();

  /*
   * type of attribute
   */
  Class<?> type();
}
```

Comment: One could add the parser, which is responsible for the current field, to the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this isn't helpful, but: In quake, which uses a very similar protocol the algorhithm is something like this (the receiver/server *knows the player ids already*).

```
ByteBuffer frame; 

int first = frame.getInt(), magic = 0x4C444732;

if(  first != magic  )
   if( !player_list.containsKey(first) )  /* must be a "string" pdu (a chat)*/
      x = new StringPDU( frame );
   else                                  /* not a chat? must be a player_id */
      x = new PlayerNamePDU( frame ); 

else                                     /* starts with magic... a game startup pdu + playername
   x = new GamePDU( frame );             /*  maybe that's the player host, or must have at least
                                             one player */
```

each PDU has a readFrame method or a constructor that reads the bytes from the ByteBuffer. It looks ugly, but short of using reflection, is necessary.

```
class GamePDU extends PDU {

    byte  command; 
    short length; 
    byte  min_players;

    short time_to_start; 
    byte  num_players;  /// after this same as a player_name packet


    GamePDU( ByteBuffer b ) {
        command = b.readByte();
        length = b.readShort();
        min_players = b.readByte();
        time_to_start = b.readShort();
        num_players = b.readByte();
        // the rest of the frame is player name
        /// players_for_game.add( new PlayerPDU(b) );
        ///  this player is in the game_start pdu to ensure that the 
        //// player_list[ num_players ] has been allocated. and has a list head. ;) Whips!!
    }
    /** if the same code is reading/writing both ends, you don't have to worry about
        endianess or signededness. ;)
        In C, in parallel, some of the game code just whips!!!
       */
}

class PDU {}
class GamePDU  extends PDU {}
class PlayerNamePDU  extends PDU {}
class StringPDU  extends PDU {}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. That's basically the 'reverse constructor'-approach I was talking about in the question. But you answer brought me to an idea. After I read the first bytes and know which PDU is to be expected, I could also pass the input stream as constructor argument instead of a byte array. This way I could also easily handle PDUs **without** length field. But for cleanness' sake that should be separated into another class.